# Drop a temp table from SQL Server Through access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010

I create a global temporary table in SQL server through ms access using a pass through query.

I am having a problem where the table just randomly drops while still working on. I had come up with a solution for this. However to do this I have to drop the temporary table. When I got to drop the table with the SQL query "DROP TABLE " ms access just freezes. Access locks me out of that table completly so I cannot even drop it in SSMS.

Any ideas?

Comment: Be wary using global temp tables. They have a lot of issues with concurrency. If you are needing to create a temp table in sql why not just move everything to sql and create a stored procedure that you can call from access instead?

Comment: I will eventually be moving all the tables to SQL and only using temp tables to store the data I am going to transfer. But at the moment I am not able to. It should have no problem dropping the table though as nothing else is locking it or even has it open

Comment: Can you use a temp table instead of a global temp table? Global temp tables are seriously a pain to deal with.

Comment: No, I tried to use temp tables but could not access them in any functions after I created them. Global temp table solved that problem.

Comment: It may have "fixed" that problem but it will generate a host of new ones. If you closed the connection where you created the temp table they will no longer be there. Maybe that is what you ran into.

Comment: The connection should be constant as it will stay open and then randomly disconnect. Not sure if they have a timeout or anything.

Comment: A global temporary table is deleted when the last session accessing it is closed.  I suspect you're having the same issue either way, that you're closing your SQL Server session.  I don't know of a way to force Access to keep a connection open.

Comment: It stays open until I close Access. Or at least it should. I can leave it for about 5 minutes without touching it, the global temp tables will still be there but then it will randomly either close the session for some reason. Or SQL will close to session. Which then deletes the tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it. I had forgotten about a hidden form which must of kept the connection to the temp table alive and locked so it could not be deleted while it was open.